# Django app only works on Debug=True Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I thought I had this solved but I guess not. I've got my Django app on Heroku, and it works perfectly with `DEBUG = True` but does not work with `DEBUG = False`.

**UPDATED QUESTION**

Now I'm just battling with this error:

2018-03-14T18:42:08.812921+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=www.powertranspro.com request_id=f75a1cec-d303-4f5c-8eee-ddf605b7c326 fwd="71.38.218.24" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http

Would someone mind reviewing my settings files to see where I've gone wrong.

**Answer**
I had conflicts with whitenoise. So I went through and deleted everything that had to do with whitenoise and moved my static files to amazon S3. I am updating my code with the correct code on this post in case anyone else has a similar problem.

First my file structure:

[image]

**base.py**

```
# settings/base.py
import os
from django.utils import timezone
from decouple import config

DEBUG = config('DEBUG', cast=bool)
GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = config('GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY')
EASY_MAPS_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = config('GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY')

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'powertrans-pro-bucket'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'config/static'),
]

STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'config.settings.storage_backends.MediaStorage'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'apps.todos.context_processors.todos_processor',
                'apps.freight_projects.context_processors.freight_projects_processor',
            ],
            'debug': DEBUG,
        },
    },
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'dal',
    'dal_select2',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'storages',
    'django_misaka',
    'bootstrap3',
    'localflavor',
    'easy_pdf',
    'django_google_maps',
    'easy_maps',
    'widget_tweaks',
    # django-allauth
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin',
    # end django all-auth
    # my created apps
    'apps.accounts',
    'apps.user_dashboard',
    'apps.customer_dashboard',
    'apps.freight_projects',
    'apps.todos',
    'apps.locations',
    'apps.loads',
    'apps.project_template_tags',
    'apps.quotes',
    # end my created apps
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

# Change 'default' database configuration with $DATABASE_URL.
#DATABASES['default'].update(dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500))

# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Allow all host headers


SITE_ID = 1
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'login_success'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'logout_confirmation'

#MAILGUN SETTINGS
EMAIL_HOST = config('EMAIL_HOST')
EMAIL_PORT = config('EMAIL_PORT', cast=int)
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = config('EMAIL_USE_TLS', cast=bool)

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
```

**production.py**

```
# settings/production.py
from .base import *
import os
from decouple import config
import dj_database_url

DEBUG = config('DEBUG', cast=bool)

GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = config('GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY')

SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['shielded-tundra-23748.herokuapp.com', '.powertranspro.com']

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(
        default=config('DATABASE_URL')
    )
}

DATABASES['default']['CONN_MAX_AGE'] = 500
```

**HEROKU LOGS**

```
2018-03-13T21:53:23.232139+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-13 21:53:23 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2018-03-13T21:53:23.234260+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-13 21:53:23 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2018-03-13T21:53:23.236062+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-13 21:53:23 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2018-03-13T21:53:23.543646+00:00 heroku[beat.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2018-03-13T21:53:23.575710+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2018-03-13T21:53:23.591368+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2018-03-13T21:53:23.591399+00:00 app[worker.1]: worker: Warm shutdown (MainProcess)
2018-03-13T21:53:23.749154+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-13 21:53:23 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2018-03-13T21:53:24.012876+00:00 heroku[beat.1]: Process exited with status 0
2018-03-13T21:53:24.023046+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2018-03-13T21:53:25.509937+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2018-03-13T21:53:43.386916+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `celery -A config worker --beat`
2018-03-13T21:53:44.117616+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-03-13T21:53:45.218810+00:00 heroku[beat.1]: Starting process with command `celery -A config beat -S django`
2018-03-13T21:53:45.731767+00:00 app[worker.1]: ['/app/config/static']
2018-03-13T21:53:46.053233+00:00 heroku[beat.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-03-13T21:53:46.582872+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn config.wsgi --log-file -`
2018-03-13T21:53:47.349183+00:00 app[worker.1]:  
2018-03-13T21:53:47.349228+00:00 app[worker.1]:  -------------- celery@b0aaf05c-7b04-4327-9e0c-10c3fe7f2965 v4.1.0 (latentcall)
2018-03-13T21:53:47.349231+00:00 app[worker.1]: ---- **** ----- 
2018-03-13T21:53:47.349234+00:00 app[worker.1]: --- * ***  * -- Linux-4.4.0-1012-aws-x86_64-with-debian-stretch-sid 2018-03-13 21:53:47
2018-03-13T21:53:47.349236+00:00 app[worker.1]: -- * - **** --- 
2018-03-13T21:53:47.349237+00:00 app[worker.1]: - ** ---------- [config]
2018-03-13T21:53:47.349240+00:00 app[worker.1]: - ** ---------- .> app:         POTRTMS:0x7f638769d7b8
2018-03-13T21:53:47.349241+00:00 app[worker.1]: - ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://h:**@ec2-34-239-77-182.compute-1.amazonaws.com:53459//
2018-03-13T21:53:47.349243+00:00 app[worker.1]: - ** ---------- .> results:     redis://h:**@ec2-34-239-77-182.compute-1.amazonaws.com:53459/
2018-03-13T21:53:47.349246+00:00 app[worker.1]: - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (prefork)
2018-03-13T21:53:47.349247+00:00 app[worker.1]: -- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
2018-03-13T21:53:47.349249+00:00 app[worker.1]: --- ***** ----- 
2018-03-13T21:53:47.349250+00:00 app[worker.1]:  -------------- [queues]
2018-03-13T21:53:47.349252+00:00 app[worker.1]:                 .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
2018-03-13T21:53:47.349254+00:00 app[worker.1]:                 
2018-03-13T21:53:47.349262+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2018-03-13T21:53:47.860250+00:00 app[beat.1]: ['/app/config/static']
2018-03-13T21:53:47.881589+00:00 app[beat.1]: celery beat v4.1.0 (latentcall) is starting.
2018-03-13T21:53:49.678712+00:00 app[beat.1]: __    -    ... __   -        _
2018-03-13T21:53:49.678762+00:00 app[beat.1]: LocalTime -> 2018-03-13 21:53:49
2018-03-13T21:53:49.678765+00:00 app[beat.1]: Configuration ->
2018-03-13T21:53:49.678767+00:00 app[beat.1]:     . broker -> redis://h:**@ec2-34-239-77-182.compute-1.amazonaws.com:53459//
2018-03-13T21:53:49.678769+00:00 app[beat.1]:     . loader -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
2018-03-13T21:53:49.678771+00:00 app[beat.1]:     . scheduler -> django_celery_beat.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler
2018-03-13T21:53:49.678773+00:00 app[beat.1]: 
2018-03-13T21:53:49.678774+00:00 app[beat.1]:     . logfile -> [stderr]@%WARNING
2018-03-13T21:53:49.678776+00:00 app[beat.1]:     . maxinterval -> 5.00 seconds (5s)
2018-03-13T21:53:49.884036+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-13 21:53:49 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
2018-03-13T21:53:49.884609+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-13 21:53:49 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:15685 (4)
2018-03-13T21:53:49.884728+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-13 21:53:49 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2018-03-13T21:53:49.889062+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-13 21:53:49 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2018-03-13T21:53:49.892636+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-13 21:53:49 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2018-03-13T21:53:50.816149+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-03-13T21:53:51.040875+00:00 app[web.1]: ['/app/config/static']
2018-03-13T21:53:51.180555+00:00 app[web.1]: ['/app/config/static']
2018-03-13T21:53:25+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.08 sample#load-avg-5m=0.13 sample#load-avg-15m=0.125 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15664184kB sample#memory-free=12008784kB sample#memory-cached=1496784kB sample#memory-redis=312336bytes sample#hit-rate=0.41381 sample#evicted-keys=0
2018-03-13T21:54:20.036317+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-13 21:54:20 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:8)
2018-03-13T21:54:20.036666+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-13 21:54:20 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:9)
2018-03-13T21:54:20.037926+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-13 21:54:20 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2018-03-13T21:54:20.038168+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-13 21:54:20 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2018-03-13T21:54:20.337323+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-13 21:54:20 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
2018-03-13T21:54:20.438551+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-13 21:54:20 +0000] [14] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14
2018-03-13T21:54:20.966862+00:00 app[web.1]: ['/app/config/static']
2018-03-13T21:54:21.114239+00:00 app[web.1]: ['/app/config/static']
2018-03-13T21:54:23.414661+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/loads/load_list/filter/" host=www.powertranspro.com request_id=912215ee-893e-431a-8849-a6cb0195ade8 fwd="71.38.218.24" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  158.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  156.                 response = response.render()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  83.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py" in render
  106.         url = self.url(context)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py" in url
  103.         return self.handle_simple(path)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py" in handle_simple
  118.             return staticfiles_storage.url(path)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py" in url
  155.         return self._url(self.stored_name, name, force)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py" in _url
  134.                 hashed_name = hashed_name_func(*args)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py" in stored_name
  422.                 raise ValueError("Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '%s'" % clean_name)

Exception Type: ValueError at /loads/load_list/filter/
Exception Value: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
Request information:
```

Comment: What's the error? If it says there's a problem with static files I'm assuming you've seen one.

Comment: Gah sorry,I'll post the heroku logs when I get back. It's basically just giving me an h12 or 503 error which sounds like it's just timing out.

Comment: You've also got `django_heroku.settings(locals())` in twice. Not sure if that's a problem, but I'd just put it at the bottom of `production.py`

Comment: Does the project build correctly when you push it to heroku? Are you able to see the worker running? Do you get an error response from your app or heroku or no response at all?

Comment: I removed the second django_heroku.settings(locals()). I also updated my original post with my Heroku logs.

@jay as far as I can tell it builds correctly, it works perfect when I change DEBUG = True inside of my convig vars in Heroku.  "able to see the worker running?" I don't know how to check to confirm but I assume that it is.

Comment: Ok looks like gunicorn maybe the issue given the two processes timing out, then the request error. It's suggested that you should avoid using gunicorn on heroku. I'd suggest trying an alternative using some help from here; https://github.com/etianen/django-herokuapp

Comment: actually now it's emailing me this error:
Exception Type: ValueError at /loads/load_list/filter/
Exception Value: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' I posted the full traceback in the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Whitenoise Docs:

> If you’re having problems with the WhiteNoise storage backend, the
>   chances are they’re due to the underlying Django storage engine. This
>   is because WhiteNoise only adds a thin wrapper around Django’s storage
>   to add compression support, and because the compression code is very
>   simple it generally doesn’t cause problems.
>
> The most common issue is that there are CSS files which reference
>   other files (usually images or fonts) which don’t exist at that
>   specified path. When Django attempts to rewrite these references it
>   looks for the corresponding file and throws an error if it can’t find
>   it.
>
> To test whether the problems are due to WhiteNoise or not, try
>   swapping the WhiteNoise storage backend for the Django one:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Also try `python manage.py collectstatic` and check if the problem still occurs.

Comment: This is a good try, First I tried commenting the STATICFILES_STORAGE out altogether, no change, 500 error with the same traceback as above.  If it change it to the one that you posted, I just get a 503 request timedout application error.

Comment: collectstatic seems to be working fine both locally and when ran on Heroku

Comment: Can you please only comment out the staticfiles_storage and try again.

Comment: So to be clear, comment out STATICFILES_STORAGE completely then push live. I'll try that when I get home

Comment: Yes, that‘s what I meant

Comment: ok commented STATICFILES_STORAGE out completely, still the same error:
Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

Comment: So if I actually bash into my app on heroku, it's running collecstatic and putting my staticfiles at app/staticfiles. There is also a static files in app/config/staticfiles.  The staticfiles in app/staticfiles literally doesn't have the right files in it. app/config/staticfiles does.  So clearly my collect static is sending things to the wrong place.

Comment: Then change STATIC_ROOT in your settings to STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, “config/staticfiles”)

Comment: I think i have the static files fixed, it's not producing the Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' anymore.  Now something is causing the app to timeout and crash. It seems there's no possible way to debug it though

Comment: How did you fix it, I am curious? Would do you mean by timeout and crash? Is the app deployed or timeout while deploying?

Comment: I just updated the screenshot of my file structure and then updated my static paths in base.py.  This is the only way I could get rid that error. The project pushes to heroku just fine, when debug is False, i get [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:66) so the page never loads. Or a request timeout 503. This could be related to ALLOWED_HOSTS, which i'll update in my production.py

Comment: So you did what I suggested, so you can mark my answer as right

I don't think it has anything to do with allowed_hosts. To help you with this one, please open a new question with the exact code and Traceback.

Comment: I'll mark this answer as correct.  Basically my whitenoise was conflicted. I ended up deleting everything pertaining to whitenoise and setup static files with Amazon S3 and it worked.  I will post my updated files in my question in case anyone else has these problems.

Comment: Can you please open up a complete new question. Anyways a h12 Request Timeout on Heroku means that your request took longer than 30 seconds. Normally in the logs it continues to process, so if you have after the error log a Completed Log it indicates everything is fine, it is just taking too long. If you don't have it something in your code may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In your project directory, where `manage.py` is located, will you add a `static` folder and put a blank `human.txt` file inside of it? Then do a git commit and push.

[image]

Comment: I've updated my file structure to show the current location of static and staticfiles. I tried moving my static out to the project directory, but then my STATICFILES_DIRS was wrong. So I tried adjusting it to os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'static'). That allowed me to push to heroku but no dice, still getting the same traceback. After trying so many things I think my file structure is probably wrong.

Comment: @KrisTryber Take a look at the image I just added. The `static` folder sits next to my `project` folder (i.e. where `settings.py` is located).

Comment: Ok i just posted a screenshot of my structure as well.